# I can't run rails console with Docker and Passenger/nginx image

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, passenger, docker-compose

I've the next docker-compose container:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
 web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/home/app/NAME_OF_MY_APP
 db:
  image: postgres:9.4
  ports:
    - "5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
```

I cannot figure out how can I run the rails console. I'm using the passenger/nginx image and everything is working. 
However, my DB is on another container and I'd like to entry at rails console to create manually a couple of users.

I tried with:

```
sudo docker-compose run web rails c
```

But it appears the next error:

```
ERROR: Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: exec: "rails": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Also, I tried:

```
sudo docker-compose run web "rails c"
```

But it stills showing the same output.

I'd like to entry at console, entry some users and store it on the postgres DB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to start your composed containers with `docker-compose up`, which starts all of your defined services. Then you can attach to your running containers by their name. You get the names of running containers from the output of `docker ps`, e.g.:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE       COMMAND  CREATED        STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d6b317a4c10b        image       "..."    27 hours ago   Up 27 hours         0.0.0.0:4284->4284/tcp   container1
4fe15ab206b5        postgresql  "..."    27 hours ago   Up 27 hours         5432/tcp                 container2
```

So in this example container2 is my database. But I want to connect to my web application. So I can directly start a shell in the running container:

```
docker exec -it container1 bash
```

which starts a bash inside container1. From there you can run any command you like, e.g. your rails console.

Also you [should use version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-1) of docker-compose files, since version 1 lacks of some features.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. It prints out the same error as before. Rails c is to entry on a ruby environment inside a rails app, So i could create users manually.

Comment: Then this is not a bug in Docker itself. It must be inside of your container, when you even can't execute `rails`. I think rails is not properly configured. When I try it on my machine with `docker run -it rails bash` and then enter `rails`, it works as expected.

Comment: Man, that was amazing! I updated my docker-compose and I entried through bash and I could have done all the stuff that I wanted. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I first thought you were kidding me when I just saw "Man, that was amazing!" ;-)

Comment: Because I pressed enter without wanting. You know sometimes when we're in hurry, this kind of things can happen :)