# docker install and enable php extension

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I trying to use Docker for my Symfony3 project I got it running but I get this error:

```
The LDAP PHP extension is not enabled.
```

It does sound right as I am using Ldap extension for my project. I have tried installing the Ldap extension using Dockerfile for my php image which seems to install it but still gives me this error.

Q1) How do I install required php extensions to my php image.
Q2) Once extension installed how do i enable it.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
 project files
    volumes_from:
        - php
    links:
        - php

php:
    image: php:5.6-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./project_code:/var/www/project
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install php5-ldap -y
```

Comment: this is alpine based, right? `a2enmod` is in alpine. is `phpenmod` valid? if so `RUN phpenmod php5-ldap` should be a help

Answer (score 0):

You need to point in your docker-compose.yml to the directory containing your Dockerfile. Then it builds your individual image based on this Dockerfile and links it as desired in docker-compose.

So you have to modify your docker-compose.yml. Lets assume you have stored your Dockerfile in the same directory as your docker-compose.yml file. Then you have to change it as follows:

```
version: '2'                              # <--
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
 project files
   volumes_from:
     - php
   links:
     - php

php:
  build: .                                # <--
  volumes:
    - ./project_code:/var/www/project
```

This builds your image as defined in the Dockerfile (currently your Dockerfile is ignored by your docker-compose.yml file). You then have to add to the Dockerfile how to enable your php module.

Comment: Hey thx! I did just that but still get the same error meassage? any clue?

Comment: Are you sure, that your extensions is correctly installed? I often debug my containers by starting a shell and then check the configuration. I described it in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248717/i-cant-run-rails-console-with-docker-and-passenger-nginx-image/39249497#39249497), Just do the same, start it with `docker-compose up`, then list the containers `docker ps` and connect to your container `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` and check your configuration

Comment: yep I did that just now firstly it states that there isynt any php.ini loaded. 2nd  i cant find the dir where all the php extensions are installed.

Comment: You can find the location with this command (run this inside your container): `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: `php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php` i go to this location and php.ini is not there only conf.d dir which is empty :/

Comment: official php images have helpers: docker-php-ext-install (for base extensions) and docker-php-ext-enable (for those you'll install from pecl). Examples: ```RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath mcrypt json zip pdo pdo_mysql``` and ```RUN pecl install redis-3.0.0 && docker-php-ext-enable redis```

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't find php.ini with `php -i | grep php.ini`

In docker, there are two php.ini files: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`
https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/